# how to obtain maximum value from database

Tags: java, database, sentiment-analysis

I am working on sentiment analysis and have obtained reviews of many recipes. I have stored recipe name, rating and reviews in database. I want highest review from each of the recipes. I am unable to do this.Please help. Thank you[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bgpd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like the query below to get your highest review.

```
SELECT A.DISHNAME, A.RATE, A.REVIEW FROM DISHRATE A, (
SELECT DISHNAME, MAX(RATE) AS RATE FROM DISHRATE GROUP BY DISHNAME
) B 
WHERE A.DISHNAME=B.DISHNAME AND A.RATE=B.RATE
```